# Why does this generic code produce a NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

Say you have a method that

- takes a threshold and an input
- raises an exception if the input is less than the threshold
- otherwise returns the input

it would look something like this:

```
<N extends Number & Comparable<N>, S extends N> S ensureLessThan(N threshold, S input) {
    if (input.compareTo(threshold) >= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input " + input + " is not less than " + threshold);
    }
    return input;
}
```

When run, this method throws a `NoSuchMethodError`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.Number.compareTo(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
```

Adding what looks like a redundant cast makes it work:

```
...
    if (((N) input).compareTo(threshold) >= 0) {
...
```

So what's going on here?

UPDATE: My Java version is

```
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)
```

And here's a runnable example: https://gist.github.com/4526536

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: How do you run it? What classes are the arguments when you make the call?

Comment: (You should be able to simplify the generics. Er, `static <T> T requireLessThan(T value, Comparable<? super T> threshold) { if (threshold.compareTo(value) <= 0) { throw ...`.)

Comment: Okay I repro'd it [here](http://ideone.com/n4dHnF) with sun-jdk-1.6.0.31 but there's no issue [here](http://ideone.com/tAefuY) with sun-jdk-1.7.0_03

Comment: On the other hand, `threshold.compareTo(input)` works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect it's a bug in the compiler.  It has staticly bound to `Number.compareTo(Object)` which doesn't exist, when it should be `Comparable.compareTo(Object)`.

Comment: Just a side note: for me the OPs example perfectly compiles and runs (Oracle 1.7_07 + Win7 64bit, eclipse 4.2.1 compiler).

Comment: @home, the java version has nothing to do w/ the error, yes eclipse does generate the cast and also uses INVOKEINTERFACE on Comparable.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (threshold.compareTo(input) < 0) {
```

will work.

It certainly appears to be a compiler error. The reason this works is that the compiler generates a checked cast to Comparable. Whereas the other way around it does not.

```
ensureLessThan(Ljava/lang/Number;Ljava/lang/Number;)Ljava/lang/Number;
  L0
        LINENUMBER 11 L0
        ALOAD 1
        CHECKCAST java/lang/Comparable
        ALOAD 2
        INVOKEINTERFACE java/lang/Comparable.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;)I
        IFGE L1
```

versus

```
ensureLessThan(Ljava/lang/Number;Ljava/lang/Number;)Ljava/lang/Number;
        LINENUMBER 11 L0
        ALOAD 1
        ALOAD 2
        INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Number.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;)I
        IFGE L1
```

Answer (score 2):

That's strange, the following code compiles and runs from my side:

```
/**
 * @author Buhake Sindi
 * @since 14 January 2013
 *
 */
public class Test {

    public static <N extends Number & Comparable<N>, S extends N> S ensureLessThan(N threshold, S input) {
        if (input.compareTo(threshold) >= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input " + input + " is not less than " + threshold);
        }
        return input;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ensureLessThan(10, 5);
    }
}
```

Tested in Eclipse Juno (Java EE), with the following JDK:

1. JDK 1.6.0_21.
2. JDK 1.7.0_09-b05

Comment: But `N extends Comparable<N>` as well, so `S` should implement `Comparable<N>`, isn't it so?

Comment: Yeah, but those generified types are erased at runtime. The JVM doesn't have those generic types while running your code.

Comment: You mean, there's no such type as `Number & Comparable<N>` at runtime, so the compiler has to choose which one to drop? In this case, it should add proper casts to all places that use methods from an interface.

Comment: -1 It should be a legal call, to agree with Jan, but if it wasn't it should be a compile error, not a runtime error.

Comment: Sorry guys, I've updated my post. There seems to be no problem at all.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not surprised the eclipse compiler is fine, actually - it's known to handle nuances of generics in many cases where javac falls flat. It would be interesting to compare the bytecode generated with what [BevynQ posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14308707/697449).

Comment: Actually, the bytecode is similar to the first bytecode BevynQ posted. and I'm not using Eclipse JDK but the actual Oracle JDK to test this.